# Is it possible to loop/wrap/connect audio out to microphone in via software on a MBP 15" Retina Late 2013?

Tags: macos, audio, sound-card, microphone

I have an application which will only take audio from the microphone input to send out to a chatroom.  The PC version of this app will take sound from the sound card as well as the microphone input.  On the Mac, this is not the case; there is only one source for audio, that is, the microphone.  Is it possible to redirect audio from an audio producing application and connect loop/wrap/connect that audio to the microphone input only chat room application?  That is, without soldering up a wired connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the software solution you're looking for: [Soundflower](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/)

Comment: Very likely the application I need.  Also, there was a "freebie" mentioned in the blog of the Soundflower site (Amoeba - LineIn) which may also do the trick. Once I've got these down, I'll report back.  Thanks. Also, a friend asked me if there is also a way to do this in Windows-8.  I guess the Windows-7 release of the chat program in question is the most flexible in terms of selecting audio sources, but many of the users are either Mac or Windows-8 users.  Go figure.

Comment: Soundflower works great on Mavericks OSX 10.9.1. The certificate is expired, but I used anyway.  If anyone can [verify the authenticity of the latest version, 1.6.6b,](https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/downloads/list) I'd appreciate it, because I'm using it successfully, regardless.  Thanks Radoo.